# Cannnot click a href

Tags: selenium, nightwatch.js

Hi i have the following code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<body class="skin-blue sidebar-mini">
<div class="wrapper">
<header class="main-header">
<aside class="main-sidebar">
<section class="sidebar" style="height: auto;">
<div class="user-panel"> </div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<ul class="sidebar-menu">
<li class="treeview">
<a href="../user/account">
<i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
<span>Basic Information</span>
</a>
</li>
<li class="treeview">
<a href="../admin/myproperties">
<i class="fa fa-list"></i>
<span>My Hotel</span>
</a>
</li>
</ul>
</section>
</aside>
```

The nightwatch code i use is this and the error is that it cant locate the element. In other site this would just work fine but here it is like it buggs

```
 module.exports = {
  tags: [''],
  'extranet' : function (client) {
    client
      .url('www.somesite.com')
      .waitForElementVisible('body', 1000)

      // --Log In Form //
      //.click('a[class="btn btn-block btn-social btn-lg btn-google"]')
      .setValue('input[name=email]', 'email@email.com')
      .setValue('input[name=password]', 'password')
      .click('button[type="submit"]')

      .click('a[href="../user/account"]')
```

SOLUTION:
Kishan Patel helped a lot so here is the Nighwatch.js that is clicking this element using Xpath

```
module.exports = {
  tags: [''],
  'extranet' : function (client) {
    client
      .url('www.somesite.com')
      .waitForElementVisible('body', 1000)
      .setValue('input[name=email]', 'email@email.com')
      .setValue('input[name=password]', 'password')
      .click('button[type="submit"]')
      .waitForElementVisible('section[class="sidebar"]', 10000)
      .useXpath()
      .click('html/body/div[1]/aside/section/ul/li[1]/a')
      .pause(5000)
      .end();

  }
};
```

Comment: Use linktext or partial link text

Comment: can you help cause i have no idea on how to do this?

Comment: Share me your code or website where there is href

Comment: I add some more code

Comment: It would be more helpful if you show us the full selenium code that you are using.   For example, what object is this .click method applied to?  Also, it looks like you have shown us just pieces of the html.  are you sure that there is no iframe in there?  you would need to switch to that first.

Comment: Please share the code and website. It would be easy to solve your issue.

Comment: Which link is this? .click('a[href="../user/account"]')

Comment: the 1st on sidebar

Comment: Can i show my code in java ? I done it in JAVA. Can you relate it? CAn you use xpath ?

Comment: no i can't show you java code cause i don't own it. But it is strange cause now acts like i don't give the .click command. i also don't know how to use xpath

Comment: Andrew. I have done your query. I have resolved it in JAVA. So should i show it in JAVA? Are you okay with it?

Comment: i am not sure. But how you did it in java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try the below code .
You apply some wait after hitting submit and it will get resolved.
I ran the same code in JAVA successfully .

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.manage().window().maximize();

driver.get("http://example.com");
```

//Login Username

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/form/div[3]/input")).sendKeys("e-mail");
```

//Password

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/form/div[4]/input")).sendKeys("password");
```

//Hit on submit

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/form/div[5]/div/button")).click();
```

//Wait for element to be visible

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("html/body/div[1]/aside/section/ul/li[1]/a")));
```

//Click on the href="../user/account"

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[1]/aside/section/ul/li[1]/a")).click();
```

Comment: thanks for helping i will be looking to translate this into nightwatch. At least i learned some stuff.

Comment: Yeah. I ran my code and it is working fine. You just need to transfer. And if you happy with my answer you can tick my answer or upvote my answer which shows you accepted my answer. Happy Learning. :-)

Answer (score 0):

First of all sorry for using this section to make a comment but I don´t have enough reputation to do so.
@Kishan Patel : could you please have a look on my issue?
[Loop is not working properly - nightwatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37394594/loop-is-not-working-properly-nightwatch)

Comment: Sorry but i m more familiar with JAVA . I could only recommend you in JAVA.
Suppose there are 50 links at below and you need to test all links whether they are true or not, Just take the title of the page and verify with the expected title. 

Simply create a method name it as verifyText or something and call this method for all 50 links.
Create a Page object model with verifyText () as common method in a separate class.
Then just create a object for that class in your test case and validate all your 50 links.

Hope I'm talking sense . M i able to relate you Rita?

Comment: @KishanPatel, thank you for your help, I can relate and understand. Now my main problem is to understand how page object works. I can only find tutorials in java. I want in javascript.

Comment: IF you want to know about page object , i can show it as a example in java then you can relate it for sure. Just post a question and comment here the question. I'll look into it, if you need my help. Happy learning. :-) 
Or else many things are available on net for page object.